# How to PopUp or Modally Present View Controller from Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

How can I create a popup that appears when a button on a Tab Bar is pressed? I would like something similar to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDWSaItF2ko.

I have tried many solutions but none have worked.

For example, I have tried this with my main view controller:

This still doesn't work though. How would I go about creating this. I know that I need to present the view controller modally and over current context, but how would I do that from a tab bar controller.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if viewController is PopupViewController {
        if let popupView = tabBarController.storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController() {
            popupView.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            tabBarController.present(popupView, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Here are some pictures that may help:

Main Storyboard:

[image: Main Storyboard]

Popup Storyboard:

[image: Popup Storyboard]

View Controller Code:

[image: View Controller Code]

Comment: "I know that I need to present the view controller modally and over current context" Actually, no. In the YouTube video you referred to, this is not a current context presentation: it's an "over full screen" presentation. It probably uses a custom presentation controller to set the size / position of the presented view (the blue square with Test and Done in it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried debug this using breakpoints in Xcode? From what I can see, the first thing you do is to check whether the view controller that should be selected is of class `PopupViewController`. Are you sure the view controller is being instantiated correctly?

And by the way I would recommend another way of instantiating the view controller from storyboard rather then:

```
tabBarController.storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController()
```

The first thing is to head over to the storyboard file itself and in the view controller you are trying to instantiate change the `Storyboard ID` to something for example the class of the storyboard (`PopupViewController` in your case).

Next you will want to try to instantiate the storyboard itself using the `init(name: String, bundle storyboardBundleOrNil: Bundle?)` initialiser:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Popup", bundle: nil)
```

And now instantiate the view controller using the `storyboard` variable like so:

```
let popupViewController  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopupViewController") as! PopupViewController
```

Finally you can give it some extra configuration and present it on the tab bar controller:

```
popupViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
tabBarController.present(popupViewController, animated: true)
```

**Edit**

Addionally to make it more *Swifty*, I recommend `guard` statement for early exit. Finally the method could look something like this:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    guard viewController is PopupViewController else { return true }
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Popup", bundle: nil)
    let popupViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopupViewController") as! PopupViewController
    popupViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    tabBarController.present(popupViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return false
}
```

Comment: I’m getting a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error, but no outlets are disconnected. It’s on the app delegate file.

Comment: what is the full error message? could you share the project on github or some other place so I could run it myself for better inspection?

Comment: I would like to tell you that this is just a test project so that I can incorporate this feature into a larger app.

Comment: Ok, so the thing causing the crash is the reference in the `Main.storyboard`. Click it and the `Popup` as the referencing storyboard. After you change that, everything should work as expected.

Comment: That almost worked, and I can't believe I missed that; however, when the popup "Pops Up" the background at first is transparent showing the content behind, but then becomes a solid black. Here is a video of this https://youtu.be/SIfvVzMCF0M

Comment: change modalPresentationStyle to `.overCurrentContext`: `popupViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext`

Currently view controller displays over tab bar controller (embeded in navigation controller), to make it cover whole screen present it on tab bar controller navigation controller like so: `tabBarController.navigationController?.present(popupViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: This is an unrelated question, but do you by any chance know why sometimes not everything is color coded the same because in the test project I shared with you .modalPresentationStyle and other things were color coded; however in my larger project they were just the default white.

Comment: You mean the source code coloring? This is Xcode at its finest. To fix this clean-build project and restart Xcode. Also removing DerivedData helps in some extreme situations.

Comment: That fixed the issue. Thanks. I never close XCode so I guess I should start. I was just kind of ignoring it, but it got to the point where it was bothering me, so thanks.

Comment: Xcode sometimes makes coding a nightmare. Get used to restarting it few times a day :P